# Use javascript to add style to every digit in a string

Tags: javascript, replace

Here's the js code:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    var myOldString = "1,2,3,4,5,6</br>1,2,3,4,5,6</br>1,2,3,4,5,6"
    var myNewString = myOldString.replace(/,/g , " ");
    document.write(myNewString);
</script>
```

Works fine, but I need to add `style="padding:5px"` to every digit.

I tried a lot of different code vairations but none of them work.

Thank's for any help!

Comment: what you need to add to every digit. what you tried show one of that

Comment: To add padding around each digit, you will need to split them into individual html components (such as spans or divs), and then apply the desired style to those components.

Comment: Hmm. You should wrap each number is a span to style it. You shouldn't try this using Regex.Replace as `myOldString` appears to be HTML...invalid HTML at that...

Comment: Looks like you don't need padding, but spacing between text: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/ You should provide an image of whatever you are trying to do..

Comment: <span style="padding:5px">1</span><span style="padding:5px">2</span><span style="padding:5px">1</span> etc

Comment: letter-spacing adds only horizontal padding but not vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
var myOldString = "1,2,3,4,5,6</br>1,2,3,4,5,6</br>1,2,3,4,5,6"
var  myNewString = myOldString.replace(/([0-9]+),?/g , ' <span style="padding:5px">$1</span> ');
document.write(myNewString);</script>
```

Comment: This is a solution. Warning to OP: What if you have `myOldString = "1,2,3,4,5,6<div id='myDiv1'></div>"`? If that would never happen, reconsider how you construct `myOldString` in the first place.

Comment: This is problematic case, but can be done by searching everything outside tags and then do another search in callback. Weird solution, but should be working `myOldString = '>'+myOldString+'<'; myOldString = myOldString.replace(/>(.*?)</g, function(){...}); myOldString = myOldString.substr(1, myOldString.length-2);`

Comment: @RGraham that's a good question, just stuck with that problem